# ExpressJs and BackboneJs Template

Tags: backbone.js, express

Right now on my index page on my app I am adding all the template files I need:

```
<script id="example" type="text/template">
// Bunch of Awesome Code
</script>
```

This is working fine now but it is starting to be a pain to deal with all these template files in one file. Is there a way to have these in many files and then concatenate them together on build?

Comment: Are you currently using any build tools in your project?

Comment: in the backend I am just using expressjs and nodejs. In the front end I am using Backbonejs with requirejs

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent article at http://blog.millermedeiros.com/node-js-as-a-build-script/ that explains how to create a build script with node.js that consolidates and minifies your files.